# Proper way to deal with external objects with functions in Python

Tags: python

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/sdk-tutorials.html) implementation of the AWS MQTT broker is confusing me.
In the code, there is this function definition:

```
def on_message_received(topic, payload, **kwargs):
    print("Received message from topic '{}': {}".format(topic, payload))
    global received_count
    received_count += 1
    if received_count == args.count:
        received_all_event.set()
```

And then the function is called like this:

```
subscribe_future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.subscribe(
    topic=args.topic,
    qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
    callback=on_message_received
)
subscribe_result = subscribe_future.result()
```

There are two things which are confusing me:

1. Why the on_message_received function is called without parameters?
2. If I want to pass a variable to on_message_received and do something to it from within that function, which would be the correct approach?

About point (2), consider the following example, which seems to be working:

```
last_message = ''

def on_message_received(topic, payload, **kwargs):
    print("Received message from topic '{}': {}".format(topic, payload))
    last_message = payload

subscribe_future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.subscribe(
    topic=args.topic,
    qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
    callback=on_message_received
)
subscribe_result = subscribe_future.result()
```

But I don't think it's the correct approach. But I don't know how I should pass the external variable to the function.

Comment: Are you sure the `on_message_received` function is called without parameters?  Do you get a `TypeError`?  I would expect that it gets called with the payload (but your code isn't what does that, the `subscribe` does it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you posted doesn't actually work because `last_message` is a local variable -- you can't access it from outside the function.  I'd suggest putting it in a handler object, like this:

```
class MessageHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_message = ''

    def on_message_received(self, topic, payload, **_kwargs):
        print(f"Received message from topic '{topic}': {payload}")
        self.last_message = payload

handler = MessageHandler()
subscribe_future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.subscribe(
    topic=args.topic,
    qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE,
    callback=handler.on_message_received
)
subscribe_result = subscribe_future.result()
print("Last message:", handler.last_message)
```

The `on_message_received` function is not *called* by your code, it is passed as an argument to `mqtt_connection.subscribe`.  The API is then what will call it (later, when there's a message), and at that time it should provide the `topic` and `payload` args to your function.

Calling `subscribe_future.result()` causes your program to stop and wait for a message to be received (i.e. it waits for the `Future` object to produce a `result`).  Note that in real life you usually don't want to immediately block on a future (because the point of a future is that it's something that will happen *in the future* and you probably have other things to do while you wait for that future to happen).